# Nested array of struct initialization: how to do if constructors for both struct are available?

Tags: go, struct

New to golang. I have two struct types (called Inner, Outer), and have constructors for each of them that I would like to use. Outer struct "has-a" 2d array of Inner struct. How do  I use the constructor for the inner type inside the constructor of outer struct, to initialize the array of inner?

```js
type Inner struct {
  val int
}

func newInner(val int) *Inner {
  i:=new(Inner)
  i.val=val
  return i
}


type Outer struct {
  members [][]Inner
  row int
  col int
}

func newOuter(row int, col int) *Outer {
  o:=new(Outer)
  o.row=row
  o.col=col
  //how do I initialize a 2d array of size [row][col] and 
  //using the constructor for inner?
  return o  
}
```

Comment: You've got `Outer` fields declared backwards, e.g. should have `members [][]Inner` not `Inner [][]member`, and `row int` not `int row`.

Comment: Thanks, editing them now

Comment: Also, you can construct a `[row][col]` sized 2-d slice of `Inner`s, but what `val` would you pass to the `newInner` constructor if your plan was to use the constructor?  `newOuter` doesn't take in any `val` argument that would be natural to pass to the `newInner` constructor.

Comment: You didn't edit as per my suggested correction.  And there are other compilation errors.  It's always helpful if you can post code that compiles.

Comment: I was planning to initialize  all "val" to 100

Comment: I corrected the members variable, appreciate your input.

Comment: I corrected the compiler errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `make` and then iterate through the matrix to initialize it.

```
    defaultInner := newInner(100)
    o.members = make([][]Inner, o.row)
    for i := 0; i < o.row; i++ {
        o.members[i] = make([]Inner, o.col)
        for j := 0; j < o.col; j++ {
            o.members[i][j] = *defaultInner
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but will all the elements of the matrix point to the same Inner variable? I ask this because all elements of members[][] are initialized to defaultInner

Comment: They are initialised to `*defaultInner` which denotes it's value and not the address.

Comment: @Ron Is there anything else to clear up in the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

```
func newOuter(row int, col int) *Outer {
    o:=new(Outer)
    o.row=row
    o.col=col

    //how do I initialize a 2d array of size [row][col] and 
    //using the constructor for inner?...
    //
    //here's one way:

    o.members = make([][]Inner, row)
    for i := 0; i < row; i++ {
        memberRow := make([]Inner, col)
        for j := 0; j < col; j++ {
            memberRow[j] = *newInner(100)
        }
        o.members[i] = memberRow
    }

    return o  
}
```